# Для чего в OpenGL нужна функция glViewport?

Tags: c++, opengl

что она делает? для чего ее применяют? и используется ли она в новых версиях OpenGL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да используется. Делает то, что написано в документации - указывает конвейеру OpenGL, в какую часть фреймбуфера ему рисовать.

Если по-умному, она задает, как пересчитывать координаты [0..1], [0..1] в прямоугольник на выходном растре.